# Access sender phone number twilio Node.js webhook

Tags: node.js, twilio

To respond if a user replies to a Twilio message, Twilio makes a post request to a server you can specify. How exactly can I access the sender phone number from the post request params? I want to be able to send them a Twilio message at a later date.

Example Code

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app = express();

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
    twiml.message('The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!');

    // is it 
    // req.params.From
    // ? 
    // that's giving me undefined

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port 8080');
});
```

The [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request) say this information is given in the "post request params" but like I indicated in the example code, `req.params.From` is returning undefined for me.

Comment: Just inspect `req.params` and you will find the sender phone number if you are posting it from the frontend or in curl

Comment: Twilio is calling this endpoint, not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The from phone number, and other parameters, are sent as form encoded parameters (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) in the body of the post request. All [the request parameters are listed in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request).

To read them, you will need to parse the body of the request using Express's [`urlencoded` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) (you can set this up for your application by calling `app.use(express.urlencoded());`) and you will then be able to read the parameters from `req.body.From`.

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
    twiml.message('The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!');

    console.log(req.body.From);

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Express server listening on port 8080');
});
```